# Why doesn't my jQuery script see that I've changed the class of an element?

Tags: jquery

I have this super simple jQuery script that I'm having trouble getting to work. I'm certainly missing something as I've done things exactly like this before with no problem.

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/full/pjJhC

```
$("div.minimize").click(function() {

    alert("Changing to RED");
    $(this).removeClass('minimize');
    $(this).addClass('maximize');

});

$("div.maximized").click(function() {

    alert("Changing to BLUE");
    $(this).removeClass('maximize');
    $(this).addClass('minimize');

});
```

The problem is that once my `<div>`'s class has been changed to `.maximize` the jQuery continues to run as if the class is still `.minimize`.

Comment: The elements are selected at the moment you want to bind the event handlers. Changes to elements afterwards do not magically bind the handlers to them. The code only runs once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the class of an element doesn't change which events are bound to it. You can however accomplish this using delegated events since with delegated events, the event is bound to a parent element that looks for matching child elements.

```
$(document).on("click","div.minimize",function() {

    alert("Changing to RED");
    $(this).removeClass('minimize').addClass('maximize');

});

$(document).on("click","div.maximized",function() {

    alert("Changing to BLUE");
    $(this).removeClass('maximize').addClass('minimize');

});
```

or better yet, a single event.

```
$("div.minimize,div.maximize").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(".minimize")) {
        alert("Changing to RED");
        $(this).removeClass('minimize').addClass('maximize');
    }
    else {
        alert("Changing to BLUE");
        $(this).removeClass('maximize').addClass('minimize');
    }
});
```

or even better than that,

```
$("div.minimize,div.maximize").click(function(){
    alert("Changing to " + $(this).is(".minimize") ? "RED" : "BLUE");
    $(this).toggleClass('maximize minimize');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't see the class change because the event was only registered on elements that matched the selector *at the time the event was bound*.

If your code is really that simple, it would be better to just test the class inside a single handler.  I've added an additional class `clickable` so that the event doesn't get bound to *every* `div` on the page:

```
$('div.clickable').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('minimize')) {
       $this.addClass('maximize').removeClass('minimize');
    } else {
       $this.addClass('minimize').removeClass('maximize');
    }
});
```

If you don't want to add the `clickable` class to your divs, then use `div.minimize,div.maximize` in the selector, per @Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you bind the click event, there is no div.maximize at that time.

In other words, just the $("div.minimize").click() is being applied and it still attached to the div.

Instead, I would attach the event to the document or the div's parent:

```
$(document).on("click", ".minimize", function() {

    alert("Changing to RED");
    $(this).removeClass('minimize');
    $(this).addClass('maximize');

});

$(document).on("click", ".maximized", function() {

    alert("Changing to BLUE");
    $(this).removeClass('maximize');
    $(this).addClass('minimize');

});
```

That should work. If the idea is just toggle between those two classes, you would simplify your code using just:

```
$(document).on("click", ".minimize, .maximize", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('minimize');
    $(this).toggleClass('maximize');
});
```